# Read ArrayList of fixed arrays

Tags: arraylist, keyvaluepair

I have an ArrayList of variable length.
Each row of the ArrayList is itself a fixed array of key/value pairs.

I need to know how to loop through the array list and load each row into a list or a class.

The language is C#. Specifically, it is MVC.  I am using a custom grid called FlexGrid by ComponentOne.

On the view the data is captured in a javascript function

```
 var cv = batchEditGrid.collectionView, items = new Array();
        if (e.extraRequestData == null) {
            e.extraRequestData = {};
        }
        for (var i = 0; i < cv.sourceCollection.length; i++) {
            items.push(cv.sourceCollection[i]);
        }
        e.extraRequestData["Items"] = items;
```

In my Controller I capture the data:

```
ArrayList items = (ArrayList)requestData.ExtraRequestData["Items"];
```

[image: This is basic structure of ArrayList. This what each row of items looks like. These are key/value pairs.]

Comment: please be more explicit and add some code :)

Comment: Also mention your programming language.

Comment: Each of those 12 items is a key/value pair.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since each item in the ArrayList was a hashtable, I ended up looping through it as follows:

```
  ParentClass ReconHdr = new ParentClass();


                foreach (System.Collections.Hashtable  o in items)
                {
                   //lineItem.LineSeq = Convert.ToInt32(item.Value);
                    ArrayList list = new ArrayList(o.Values);
                    ChildClass lineItem = new ChildClass();

                    lineItem.StmntDocNum = list[0].ToString();
                    lineItem.PrtlAmt = Convert.ToDouble(list[1]);
                    lineItem.GLAcctCode = list[2].ToString();
                    lineItem.LineSeq = Convert.ToInt32(list[3]);
                    lineItem.ClinicID = Convert.ToInt32(list[4]);
                    lineItem.PrtlTranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[5]);
                    lineItem.StmntTranDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[6]);
                    lineItem.PrtlFinRptDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[7]);
                    lineItem.StmntEndDate = Convert.ToDateTime(list[8]);
                    lineItem.StmntAmt = Convert.ToDouble(list[9]);
                    lineItem.PrtlDocNum = list[10].ToString();
                    lineItem.PrtlUniqueID = list[11].ToString();

                    ReconHdr.AddItem(lineItem);

                }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this.

```
 ArrayList<String[]> myarraylist;//Presumably you have this;

 for(String[] data : myarraylist)
 new myClass(data[0],data[1]);
```